# Enable net.tcp protocol from Web.config

Tags: wcf, web-config, iis-7.5, net.tcp

I have WCF service that has http and net.tcp endpoints. I have deployed the service to IIS 7.5 (Server 2008R2), everything is working good.

My question is this, is there a way to set enabled protocols for the IIS application through Web.config?? Right now I have to go to the Application in IIS and manually change the Advanced settings and add **net.tcp** to the list of available protocols before the service can be activated, see pic for the screenshot.

[image: IIS Protocol Settings]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: @John, fixed according to the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this setting isn't available via web.config. It can be set either via the IIS Manager as you're doing, or via the AppCmd.exe command-line utility, as in the example below:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/FirstWcfHost" /enabledProtocols:http,net.tcp
```

Comment: I see, do you have more insight as to why?

Comment: See the response from x0n for the reason.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a web-scoped setting. It is web application (app pool) scoped one, so it is in the applicationHost.config file.